# Hide the parent div text only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div with two child divs inside it.

How can i hide the text of parent div (parent text) keeping "child1 text" and "child2 text" visible.

```
<div id="parent">
    parent text
    <div id="child1">child1 text</div>
    <div id="child2">child2 text</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You would have to wrap `parent text` in an element and hide that element.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: There is no way you can generalize this except for putting the text in to another element...

Comment: I don't think it is possible to hide the text content, but if it is ok to wrap the text content in somethingk like a `span` then you can hide it

Comment: Check whether this will do http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zzSB6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can only hide actual elements, and hiding elements also hides all the elements children, so you'll have to wrap the textnodes in their own elements, and then hide those elements :

```
$('#parent').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType==3;
}).wrap('<span class="text"></span>');

$('.text').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HjPez/)

Comment: thank u all taht solved my problem.what have u used nodeType == 3
.what is its functionality

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var x = $('#parent').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).wrap('<span/>').parent().hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zzSB6/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$('#parent').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
})​.remove();​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igijow/1/)**

Comment: Maybe you should mention that you cannot simply "show" the text anymore, since you removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking to straight HTML/JavaScript, you could wrap "parent text" in a `<span>`.  I.e,

```
<div id="parent">
    <span id="parent-text-id">parent text</span>    
    <div id="child1">
        child1 text
    </div>    
    <div id="child2">
        child2 text
    </div>     
</div>
```

That way, you can reference that text whenever you want to hide it.  Good luck!

Comment: @Rameez, I don't have the reputation to add comments to others' answers, so I'll just put the comment on my own answer.  In the spirit of the community, you should mark your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative answer, the others will return and hide all text nodes within `#parent`, this will only hide the first `childNode`:

```
$(document.getElementById('parent').childNodes[0]).wrap('<span/>').parent().hide();
```